# Could not install package 'Emgu' with .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 in a specific project

Tags: c#, nuget-package, emgucv

I have a Visual Studio 2022 C# Project (4.7.2 Framework) and want to add

```
Emgu.Cv.Runtime.Cuda and Emgu.runtime.windows.cuda.dnn.cnn.infer
```

nuget files to the project but i could not do it.

I have an error:

```
"Could not install package 'Emgu.runtime.windows.cuda.blas 11.3.44'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'"
```

However, i started a new project and i could add these Emgu-CV nuget files easily on the same PC.

Also i tried to install Emgu.Cv packages from nuget packages in Visual Studio. I could add:

```
 Emgu.CV
 Emgu.Bitmap
 Emgu.UI
```

but

```
 Emgu.CV.runtime.windows
```

can not be loaded.

So, i can not run Emgu on this project.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I found some nuget packages installed before. I've uninstalled all runtime nugets and i could install my emgu files.

Comment: Hey, can you specify the versions you installed? The same problem here!